# Windows 10 Connected Standby causing major processor throttling on battery

Tags: laptop, cpu, hibernate, standby, throttling

I have a Dell XPS 9710 (laptop) with an i7 11800H, currently with Connected Standby turned ON. I know I know, it's an easy Registry Entry to disable, but gosh darn it I LIKE how quickly it gets my computer up and running so fast! Open the lid and BAM it's ready!

However, I noticed not too long ago that the processor gets majorly throttled when I'm running on battery, like MAJORLY. Here are some comparison screenshots.

AC Power:
[AC Power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhpW9.png)

On Battery power:
[Battery Power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvTMC.png).

And of course, the only power setting available is "Balanced" and the only major option I have is changing the slider on the Power Mode Pop-up in the lower right [Power Mode: Best Performance enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Aca.png).

I've already done the "Disable CS" with the registry entry of "PlatformAoAcOverride" from [this guide here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/only-balanced-power-plan-available-on-windows) that enables all other power plans. While this works to fix the throttling, I find myself restarting more frequently due to the lagging that happens after waking up from hibernating (choppy animations are a clear sign of this).

So my question is this: is there anyway to

1. keep Connected Standby running while
2. completely disabling processor power throttling when on battery?

The power mode slider doesn't seem to do anything at all, Balanced Power Plan has no options to manage the processor power, and I've disabled the "Intel Processor Power" thing in the BIOS, and none of these has any effect. Do I just have to choose one or the other (CS or not CS)?

Answer (score 0):

After tooling around some more while waiting to hear from the community, I think I may have stumbled upon the answer. I found [this guide](https://www.windowsdigitals.com/disable-cpu-throttling-settings-windows-11/) and started all the way down at number 3 (because the first two didn't apply to a computer with CS Enabled).

Essentially, you're going to edit the group policy value for PowerThrottling, and then you'll also edit (or add, like I had to) the registry value for PowerThrottling. Restart, and you should be good.

I have some more testing to do, and some programs still have a little noticeable lag (like Photoshop), but overall CPU performance is still high enough. In the "Details" pane of the Task Manager, no processes have Power Throttling enabled!

I don't want to say this is definitively solved yet, as the processor speed is still below the maximum, but it is definitely an improvement.